# TeXnicCentre can't install new packages

Tags: miktex, texniccenter

I'm running TeXnicCentre on top of MiKTeX on Windows 10. I have been having some issues with the MiKTeX package manager/updater so uninstalled and reinstalled MiKTeX. That seems to have fixed the issues at the MiKTeX level, however, when I try and compile a document in TeXnicCenter and it needs to install a package a get the following error:

```
2017-07-06 09:30:32,511+0100 INFO  pdflatex - starting with command line: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex.exe" -max-print-line=120 -interaction=nonstopmode Supplementary_info2.tex
2017-07-06 09:30:32,528+0100 INFO  pdflatex - running 'initexmf --quiet --update-fndb' to refresh the file name database
2017-07-06 09:30:42,633+0100 INFO  pdflatex - going to create file: pdflatex.fmt
2017-07-06 09:30:56,784+0100 INFO  pdflatex - installing package setspace triggered by tex\latex\setspace\setspace.sty
2017-07-06 09:30:58,852+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Unknown MiKTeX exception.
2017-07-06 09:30:58,859+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Info: =""
2017-07-06 09:30:58,859+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Source: 
2017-07-06 09:30:58,859+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 0
2017-07-06 09:34:28,961+0100 INFO  pdflatex - starting with command line: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex.exe" -max-print-line=120 -interaction=nonstopmode Supplementary_info2.tex
2017-07-06 09:34:28,989+0100 INFO  pdflatex - running 'initexmf --quiet --update-fndb' to refresh the file name database
2017-07-06 09:34:34,458+0100 INFO  pdflatex - going to create file: pdflatex.fmt
2017-07-06 09:34:48,258+0100 INFO  pdflatex - installing package setspace triggered by tex\latex\setspace\setspace.sty
2017-07-06 09:34:50,153+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Unknown MiKTeX exception.
2017-07-06 09:34:50,153+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Info: =""
2017-07-06 09:34:50,153+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Source: 
2017-07-06 09:34:50,153+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 0
2017-07-06 09:36:39,379+0100 INFO  pdflatex - starting with command line: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex.exe" -max-print-line=120 -interaction=nonstopmode Supplementary_info2.tex
2017-07-06 09:36:43,358+0100 INFO  pdflatex - installing package textgreek triggered by tex\latex\textgreek\textgreek.sty
2017-07-06 09:36:44,755+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Unknown MiKTeX exception.
2017-07-06 09:36:44,755+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Info: =""
2017-07-06 09:36:44,755+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Source: 
2017-07-06 09:36:44,755+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 0
```

It seems I can install the packages manually via the package manager put not 'on the fly' via TeXnicCentre. Given that I've just reinstalled TeXnicCentre and there are a lot of missing packages a fix for this would be very helpful!

Comment: TeXnicCentre is old, looks abandoned and always had problems to handle the miktex on-the-fly correctly. So I would say either use another editor or live with the missing on-the-fly (you can compile once on the command line to get the missing packages).

Comment: Could you recommend another good editor? How do I compile on the command line (running in Windows 7)?

Comment: For novices, texmaker is usually a good option, it helps you while you write (similar to TC, but perhaps more intuitive), it comes with its own build in PDF viewer which is already setup for synctex (aka jumping between PDF and source. If you want even more features, texmakers evil cousin (they have the same ancestor)  texstudio might be worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using MikTeX, you have TeXworks on your PC. Just load your source file in TeXworks and compile it. MikTeX's automatically package handler works from TeXworks, so after one compilation, you can continue editing with TeXnicCentre.

It is many years since I used TeXnicCentre. In those days, you had to configure MikTeX’s automatic package manager so that it *not* asked for permission to install missing package.

Answer (score 0):

IF `setspace.sty` is not found, and you cannot even install through MiKTex Package Manager (you will not find respective ftp repository and also you can't change). The only reason is older version of MiKTeX on your machine, The solution is only to unInstall older version of MikTeX and Download and install Latest MikTeX. This will install all packages with updated ftp active repository addresses, and also `setspace.sty` will be installed too.